# mimick google results buttons, can that be done via jquery?

Tags: jquery

when your signed into google, and you search for anything you get the result back.
you then have these buttons where you can bump the result up/down, or even delete it.

when you delete a result, it disappears and then you get this animated image of a cloud that disappears.

How do they inject that image before it disappears?

**(BTW, I want to see that image, how can I find out the url to that image?)**

Answer (score 3):

Developer tools of any decent browser([Chrome](http://blog.chromium.org/2009/06/developer-tools-for-google-chrome.html), [Firefox](http://getfirebug.com/), [Opera](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/), [Internet Explorer 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565628(VS.85).aspx)) are able to show you a detailed view of all HTTP requests.

http://www.google.com/images/swxa.png

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you could click the button, the entry would be replaced with a cloud-exploding gif, and then the result would be hidden. Maybe the id of that result would be associated with a "dont-show" list which itself is associated with your ipaddress/userid/session.

```
# Just an idea - untested
$(".result .deleteButton").click(function(){
  $(this)
    .parent()
    .html($(".cloud").clone())
    .fadeOut();
});
```